# setting two values in a matrix at the same time

Tags: matlab

This is a very basic MATLAB syntax question.

I'm trying to set the first column of a 2x1000 matrix in Matlab to 10 and 30.

This is giving me an error:
xy((1,1),(2,1)) = ([10],
                    [30])

What am I doing wrong?

Many thanks.

Comment: I hope this doesn’t sound too rude. Why don’t you read the documentation? You’ll be much better off learning things properly, rather than trying random syntax and asking here why it doesn’t work. Read this: https://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html

Answer (score 1):

This hardly seems to warrant an answer, but try:

```
xy(:,1) = [10;30]
```

Here `:` means "all elements" in that dimension.
Alternatively you could do either of these:

```
x([1,2], 1) = [10;30]
x(1:2, 1) = [10;30]
```

In MATLAB you use round brackets (parentheses) to index into arrays, and use square brackets to define literal arrays. As you can see you can index arrays with arrays, and assign arrays to sub-arrays.